# Vim colors debugging

Tags: linux, vim

I've been using ubuntu's latest vim, and the i reformat my computer (but /home still the same) then i install archlinux's latest vim, somehow the color highlighting are not working anymore, is there a way to find out what's wrong with it?

EDIT: my vim --version

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb  5 2013 22:52:17)
Included patches: 1-798
Compiled by ArchLinux
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
+digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi 
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext 
-hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall 
+linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname 
+mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm 
+mouse_sgr -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_urxvt +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang 
-mzscheme +netbeans_intg +path_extra +perl +persistent_undo +postscript 
+printer +profile +python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby 
+scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop 
+syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse
 +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual 
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup 
+X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2  -I/usr/local/include  -march=i686 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -lruby -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

my .vimrc

```
$ cat .vimrc 

" Vundle: https://github.com/gmarik/vundle
" installation: vim +BundleInstall +qall
set nocompatible
filetype off 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()
" installer
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'           
" ruby, rails
Bundle 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'       
Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails'
" folder tree
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'     
" folder tree with tabs
Bundle 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs' 
" recover unsaved files
Bundle 'chrisbra/Recover.vim'    
" find everything, use <Leader\>T or <Leader\>B
Bundle 'wincent/Command-T'       
" change matching pair, use :cs[from][to]
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'      
" expand snippet, use <tab>
Bundle 'msanders/snipmate.vim'   
Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
" easy jump, use <Leader\><Leader\>[char]
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion' 
" syntax tree, use Ctrl+B
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'
" split screen, use :ConqueTerm or :ConqueTermTab or :ConqueTermSplit or :ConqueTermVSplit [cmd]
Bundle 'rson/vim-conque'
" autocomplete for tag
"Bundle 'simple-pairs' " broken after upgrade on arch
" indentation guides
Bundle 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
" ruby's end on every statement
Bundle 'tpope/vim-endwise'
" MRU, use ctrl+P
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
" statusbar
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'
" autocomplete
"Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
" javascript, html5, jquery, css3:
Bundle 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Bundle 'othree/html5.vim'
Bundle 'jQuery'
Bundle 'indenthtml.vim'
Bundle 'mutewinter/vim-css3-syntax'
filetype plugin indent on

" show hidden in nerdtree
" let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
" t: Open the selected file in a new tab
" i: Open the selected file in a horizontal split window
" s: Open the selected file in a vertical split window
" I: Toggle hidden files
" m: Show the NERD Tree menu
" R: Refresh the tree, useful if files change outside of Vim
" ?: Toggle NERD Tree's quick help

" auto open nerdtree-tabs in console
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1

" auto close when no other window except nerd tree
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif

" shortcut for nerdtree is Ctrl+n ==> normally :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
map <C-n> <C-w><C-w>

" shortcut for switching tab is Ctrl+Up/Ctrl+Down
map <C-Up> :tabn<CR>
map <C-Down> :tabp<CR>

" tagbar toggle
nmap <C-b> :TagbarToggle<CR>

let g:tagbar_type_ruby = {
    \ 'kinds' : [
        \ 'm:modules',
        \ 'c:classes',
        \ 'd:describes',
        \ 'C:contexts',
        \ 'f:methods',
        \ 'F:singleton methods'
    \ ]
\ }

" from stackoverflow forum
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1 
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1

" open shell Ctrl+M
map <C-M> :ConqueTermSplit bash<CR>

" let conque close when bash ends, doesn't work
" let g:ConqueTerm_CloseOnEnd = 1

" autocomplete maps to Ctrl+space
imap <C-Space> <C-x><C-o>
imap <C-@> <C-Space>

" Ctrl+Backspace is delete previous word, need to patch libvte
imap <C-BS> <C-W>

" Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down to move current line
function! s:swap_lines(n1, n2)
    let line1 = getline(a:n1)
    let line2 = getline(a:n2)
    call setline(a:n1, line2)
    call setline(a:n2, line1)
endfunction
function! s:swap_up()
    let n = line('.')
    if n == 1
        return
    endif
    call s:swap_lines(n, n - 1)
    exec n - 1
endfunction
function! s:swap_down()
    let n = line('.')
    if n == line('$')
        return
    endif
    call s:swap_lines(n, n + 1)
    exec n + 1
endfunction
noremap <silent> <c-s-up> :call <SID>swap_up()<CR>
noremap <silent> <c-s-down> :call <SID>swap_down()<CR>

" map common mistakes
:command WQ wq
:command Wq wq
:command W w
:command Q q

" auto indent
" use :set paste or :set nopaste for pasting without/with autoindent
set shiftwidth=2 
set tabstop=2 
set smartindent
set expandtab

" CUT = Ctrl+X / Shift+Del
" COPY = Ctrl+C / Ctrl+Ins
" PASTE  = Ctrl+V / Shift+Ins
" VISUAL = Ctrl+Q
" SAVE = Ctrl+S
" UNDO = Ctrl+Z
" REDO = Ctrl+Y
" MENU = Alt+Space
" SELECT ALL = Ctrl+A
" NEXT TAB = Ctrl+Tab
" CLOSE WINDOW = Ctrl+F4
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set t_Co=256
set background=dark
set syntax=on
set showmatch
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set hlsearch
set backspace=indent,eol,start
colorscheme heraldkyz
```

my term env variable:

```
$ echo $TERM
```

xterm-256color

Comment: Show us your vim config, including a full dump of `$ vim --version`, and tell us what terminal emulator you use, if you use screen or tmux and what is the value of `$TERM`.

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the vim pacakge on archlinux problem's..

Note: The vim package is meant to be as lightweight as possible; hence, it does not support Python, Lua, and Ruby interpreters, nor does it support X server options (this means that it will not support copy and paste from the X clipboard). If you require these options, install the gvim package instead (it includes the vim binary as well).

src: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim

you must install gvim package instead

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
syntax enable
```

on vimrc

src: 7th post on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=619027